# How to show runspace child powershell objects streams on host console?

Tags: powershell, runspace

I have some [Powershell objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (created with `[PowerShell]::Create()`) acting as threads in my powershell application.

How can I show the streams data (Verbose and Error streams) on the invoker's console, during the run itself, and not only after the thread terminates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$VerbosePreference` needs to be set to "continue" on the thread environment. It can be also applied to the pipeline before the real execution script:

```
$pipeline = [PowerShell]::Create()
$pipeline.RunspacePool = $pool

if ($PSBoundParameters['Verbose'].IsPresent) {
    $pipeline.AddScript({ $VerbosePreference = "Continue" }, $false).Invoke()
    $pipeline.Commands.Clear()
}

... $pipeline execution code ...
```